# Using gtk on Raspberry Pi

Tags: gtk, raspberry-pi4

I am new to Raspberry Pi (I have a 4B) and to stackoverflow. I am trying to use gtk. I have no trouble compiling and running multiple simple examples from the web. However, while every example creates a window, no other gtk commands (e.g., text, buttons, border width) work. I just get a blank window on every example. An example of such a program, taken from C_GUI_Programming.pdf at raspberrypi.org is:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
 gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
 GtkWidget *win = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
 GtkWidget *btn = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Close window");
 gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (win), btn);
 gtk_widget_show_all (win);
 gtk_main ();
}
```

How can I get gtk to do more than create a blank window?

Comment: "no other gtk commands (e.g., text, buttons, border width) work" You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Normally gtk_widget_show_all (win); does the job. Did you tried to run gtk_widget_show ( btn ); also?....just for curiosity.

Comment: in the above example are you getting a blank window??? or a window with a button ?? if it was an empty window did the open with some width and height or did it open with 0 width and 0 height ?? '

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I believe my trouble was in my make file. Not being a Unix guy I've always had trouble with make files. In any event I found a superb tutorial on gtk at https://prognotes.net/gtk-glade-c-programming/ and am j up and running again.